# Does your boss have to let you vote?

Tags: united-states, law, voting, united-kingdom

If you have a job that sometimes involves travel or long high pressure days , is it legal for your boss to not allow you time off to vote?

I would be interested in the situation in the UK and US.

Comment: You might want to try this question on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the US, yes, they have to accommodate you getting to vote. If you are traveling, however, it's on you to get a absentee ballot.

Comment: @DA What if the boss sends you off to travel with little notice?

Comment: @Lembik that's an interesting scenario. Good question.

Comment: @DA. do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Philipp well, hence it only being a comment. :) After googling, it appears there are no federal laws in the US for this. However, most (?) states have enacted laws and regulations to address it.

Comment: Oh, here's a good summary of it on a state-by-state level: http://www.findlaw.com/voting-rights-law.html

Comment: In Spain, yes, up to four hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the United States, I think the best answer here is *it depends*.  As @DA mentioned in the comments, there is no federal law regarding this particular aspect of voting rights.  The states (some of them anyway) have stepped up, and I found a pretty useful link [here](http://www.findlaw.com/voting-rights-law.html) that summarizes the current patchwork of laws.

<sub>NB: It looks like that page was made for the 2012 election, so I am taking those summaries to be accurate as of that timeframe.</sub>

I think the best summary of the current status of whether or not your boss is required to allow you to "take off" to go vote comes from [here](http://www.workplacefairness.org/votingrights):

> **I'm scheduled to work on Election Day. Do I have a right to take time off from work to vote?**
>
> Not necessarily. Depending on where you live, the answer may be "yes, definitely," "no, not really," or "it depends." This is an area of the law dealt with on a state-by-state basis, even during the national presidential elections held every four years. So your right to vote during work time depends on what your state law says.

Looking through the list from the first link, it looks like there's a few broad categories of the types of laws states have (or failed to have) enacted:

**1. No specific law requiring time off to vote.** (21 total)

> Connecticut, D.C., Delaware, Florida, Idaho, Indiana, Louisiana, Maine, Michigan, Mississippi, Montana, New Hampshire, New Jersey, North Carolina, North Dakota*, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina, Vermont, Virginia

I am including North Dakota in this list, even though the law *"encourages employers to [allow time off of work to vote]"* because encourging something is wholly distinct from requiring it.

**2. Employees who begin their work day less than X hours after polls open and finish less than X hours before polls close are entitled to Y hours leave to vote** (25 total)

> Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, California, Colorado, Georgia, Hawaii, Illinois, Iowa, Kansas, Maryland, Missouri, Nebraska, Nevada, New Mexico, New York, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Washington, West Virginia, Wisconsin, Wyoming

It should be noted here that each of these states' laws are worded somewhat differently with somewhat different restrictions.  For instance, in Tennessee the employee must request leave by noon the day before Election Day.

**3. Employees may take X hours off to go vote** (2 Total)

> Kentucky, Minnesota

In Minnesota, those hours are specified to be in the 'morning'.

This being the United States, there are some notable outliers.

**Arkansas**

> Employers must create schedules so that each employee will have the opportunity to vote.

That's seems fair enough to me.

**Massachusetts**

> No employee of a manufacturing, mechanical or mercantile establishment must work during the first two hours after the polls open if the employee applied for a leave of absence during this period.

Apparently the rest of us are out of luck if our employers don't want us to vote.

**Ohio**

> Employers cannot fire or threaten to fire an employee for taking a reasonable amount of time to vote. Paid only for salaried employees.

And (my personal favorite)...

**Puerto Rico**

> Election day is a legal holiday in Puerto Rico and most employees have the day off work. Employers running a business in operation on election day, however, must establish shifts allowing employees to go to the polls between 8am and 3pm.

**In Regards To Travel**

It is my impression that none of the states have laws on the books that take this into account.  So while you may be entitled to have the morning off to go to the polls, you may be physically unable to reach your polling station depending on where your employer had you travel to on the day prior to election day.  You still have a right to vote, but I would consult your local board of elections and acquire an absentee ballot in order to have your voice heard.

Additionally, [many jurisdictions](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/absentee-and-early-voting.aspx) include no-excuse early voting, or in the case of WA, OR and CO, offer *all mail-in voting* where a ballot is automatically mailed to all eligible voters and there are no traditional polling precincts.  The link above provides a color-coded state by state map depicting the current status of each state in regards to absentee and early voting (thanks for the comment from reirab).

**Practically, could an employer prevent an employee from voting?**

As was noted in the comments, I believe the answer here is *yes* it is *possible*.  I think from the vast diversity of employers out there and, judging from the fact that [many](http://inthesetimes.com/working/entry/14046/romney_instructed_employers_to_tell_employees_how_to_vote_in_conference_cal) [employers](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/politics/108140/coal-miners-donor-mitt-romney-benefactor) urge ([coerce](http://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/10/can-your-boss-threaten-to-fire-you-if-you-dont-vote-for-romney/263709/)?) their employees to vote a certain way certainly implies that the will to affect outcomes of elections is there for employers.  However, the possible downsides of doing this to an employee (which include a devout pummeling in the court of public opinion) would no doubt deter all but the most ardent employers from actively preventing employees from voting which, as noted by others, would be minimally effective at best.

That being said and this being the US, we know it has already happened.  I stumbled across [this series of letters](http://ldhi.library.cofc.edu/exhibits/show/after_slavery_educator/unit_six_documents/document_seven) which describe a sawmill owner's efforts to disenfranchize both black and white employees of his from voting for the "[radical ticket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_Republican)" in South Carolina, 1868.

Comment: Thank you for this. As a matter of practicality I assume you have to apply for an absentee ballot some time in advance so that doesn't work unless you have plenty of warning of the travel.

Comment: What about employees that cannot leave work without damage to it? For instance those under medical experiments or testing Mars/orbital conditions in a spacecraft simulator etc?

Comment: I wish the rest of the country took Puerto Rico's approach.

Comment: @Anixx - That's when you get an absentee ballot.  Those are unlikely to come up out of nowhere the day before election day.

Comment: @Bobson It is very odd that there is no law to prevent employers deliberately sabotaging their employees chancing of being able to vote but sending them to travel at the last moment or just keeping them late at work. You can easily imagine the boss might like one party while the lowly paid staff like another.

Comment: @Lembik - I'm not sure that "odd" is the word I'd use for it, but it is true (in most states, anyway).  However, if they're blatant enough about it, they may open themselves up to a lawsuit.  Additionally, you can always quit, or go vote and then dare them to fire you for it.  And there's always people who would want to vote and can't, because they get hit by a bus and are in a coma that day (or otherwise incapacitated).  And this may be very cynical of me, but there are so few state & national elections where one vote matters that I really can't see any employer even caring that much.

Comment: @Bobson Which lawsuit would they leave themselves open to? I mean what could you sue for?  I really don't buy your point about one vote not mattering. If individuals can legally prevent other individuals from voting that has to be bad.

Comment: @Lembik - Possibly a discrimination suit, or a civil rights violation.  I'm not a lawyer, but there have certainly been successful suits for less important things.  Also, like I said, you can't be prevented from voting *if you care enough*.  If you'd rather vote than keep your job, you can do that.  It's not like election day comes as a surprise every year - if your boss wants to send you out of town unexpectedly, you say no.

Comment: @Bobson I am talking about voting and suffering no detriment at work for doing so. I believe this should be a fundamental right.

Comment: @Lembik - I don't disagree, and I would love to see better laws to encourage voting in place, but I also don't think it's nearly as big an issue as other aspects of the voting process (such as gerrymandering).  When most House races are forgone conclusions, one vote here and there *really* doesn't tilt the scales much.

Comment: If your boss pulled some such trick to prevent employees from voting once -- whether because he's afraid they'll vote for the wrong person or he just doesn't want to lose the work hours -- everyone would then know and the next year you get an absentee ballot. It's a trick that could really only be pulled once or twice. And besides, if your boss is such a jerk that he schemes to lock you in the office so you can't vote, he's probably a jerk in other ways too, and you should be looking for another job.

Comment: @Lembik Laws are usually made in reaction to significant threats. Since the situation you describe doesn't seem to have been a problem so far, it hasn't been specifically addressed. Also, in addition to perhaps being sued for a civil rights violation, it would be _extremely_ bad PR for the business in question and would almost certainly result in a law being made to prevent it in the future. Additionally, it's very unlikely to affect any election at a state or federal level, though it could possibly make a difference in a local election, especially in less populous areas.

Comment: This answer is good, but it might also be good to mention early voting, which is also available in the vast majority of states and can greatly increase the ability of workers to get to polls. Wikipedia claims that 30.6% of votes in the 2008 Presidential election were from early voters.

Comment: @Jay I take your point although often there is no other comparable job prospect that doesn't involve moving house.

Comment: @reirab I think you are right about the law although I am not sure about the rest of your argument.  The employer can claim it was an accident of timing of course and if most employers voted differently to their employees (which seems plausible) then a general pattern of behaviour of this sort could make quite a difference.

Comment: @Lembik But a general pattern of such behavior would be pretty easy to identify (surely the employees would complain loudly) and it a law would be passed ASAP in addition to being a _huge_ hit on the public image of the employer(s). It should probably also be noted that the sort of employees that are commonly sent on last-minute business trips are generally not the sort that have a strong tendency to vote contrary to how many business owners would vote. Certainly, sending a bunch of blue-collar factory workers on a 'business trip' on election day would raise lots of red flags.

Comment: @Lembik Not to mention the issue of it being extremely expensive to the employer for very, very little chance of affecting anything aside from perhaps who's on the local school board.

Comment: Yeah. If there was some local election where one candidate had policies that the owner of a big factory favored, while the other candidate had policies that the employees tended to favor, conceivably the boss could pull some trick to make it hard for the employees to vote so that his preferred candidate can win. I don't know what that would be in a local election. The only thing I can think of would be labor relations laws, and those are national, not local. A factory owner might have a big interest in a zoning change or local pollution ...

Comment: ... ordinance, but in that kind of case the employees have the same interests as the owner -- they both have a vested interest in seeing this company do well. If you're talking about general national policy, taxes or regulations or some such, it is very unlikely that the employees of one company could change the outcome. I suppose all the employers could get together in a vast conspiracy to stop their employees from voting against a candidate who would give a new tax break to big corporations or something, but that would take a huge and well-planned conspiracy to succeed.

Comment: @lembik RE other job prospects: Of course that depends on where you live and what sort of job you have. If your present job is undesirable enough for whatever reason, you almost always have alternatives. Yes, it may require moving or other inconveniences. Whether it's worth it depends on how undesirable the job is. If you are really trapped in your present job with a boss who manipulates and abuses you, and you have no practical alternatives, getting time off to vote is likely very low on your list of concerns. :-)

Comment: You might want to add that some states such as Oregon, where there is no law regarding time off for voting, conduct all their elections by mail. Voters can vote from the comfort of their own homes and have usually about three weeks to do so, so it is unnecessary for elections to be accommodated by employers in any way, and there is no way for employers to affect voting.

Comment: @JDoe That's covered in the 2nd paragraph under 'In regards to travel'

Answer (score 4):

Since polling stations are [open from 7am to 10pm](https://www.gov.uk/voting-in-the-uk/polling-stations) and it is forbidden to [work that long](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=706&langId=en&intPageId=205), certainly without a break, it's not clear that any specific rule is needed. If your boss really demands your presence from 7am to 10pm, he or she is probably already doing something illegal.

Furthermore, since you can easily vote [by post](https://www.gov.uk/voting-in-the-uk/postal-voting) or [by proxy](https://www.gov.uk/voting-in-the-uk/voting-by-proxy), it could be argued that work obligations do not threaten your voting rights *per se*. Work is in fact cited on the website as one of the reasons you can use to apply to vote by proxy.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I am talking about two scenarios. a) Your boss sends you away to work from another site.  That is you can't physically access the polling booth where you are registered or b) You are planning on voting after work but your boss suddenly announces you have to work late.  You have to register  at least 11 working days before election day to vote by post so your boss can just announce the travel after that date has passed.

Comment: Also, you can have a break of half an hour or even a whole hour and still not be able to get to the polling booth and back so I don't think working time regulations help here either.

Comment: Finally, those working time regulations are full of loop-holes in the UK. See https://www.gov.uk/maximum-weekly-working-hours/weekly-maximum-working-hours-and-opting-out

Comment: @Lembik The loopholes pertain to the weekly total, not the daily maximum/break requirements. But it's certainly possible to think of many things that make voting more difficult. A simpler and more common one would simply be working far away from your place of residence for a week at a time (think lorry drivers, construction workers, etc.). At the same time, you can easily see why requiring employers to pay a trip back home or free their employees for a day to come back and vote would be quite an extraordinary requirement.

Comment: What I am saying is that the law assumes voting should be possible without special measures for many factory/retail/office jobs and voting by post or proxy is there for other situations. Sure, there can be corner cases and last minute changes but it's not possible to be certain to cover all possible scenarios. How could such a rule that look like? If half an hour is not enough, should you be able to take as much time as you need?

Comment: I suppose my point is a) it should be a crime for an employer to deliberately to try to prevent an employee from voting and b) the employer should provide a prearranged time slot in which you can vote in the day and not be allowed to change that. Clearly the slot has to have some reasonable maximum period in length like 2 hours.  The post and proxy votes don't address the case of the employer being malicious or just negligent.  If you have to be away, the employer should be required to give you enough notice to register for a postal vote.

Comment: @Lembik I think I see what you mean. *Deliberately* interfering with the voting process is certainly a valid issue but I didn't understand your question to be about this at all. It might be worth posting a new question more specifically about that.

Comment: On the other hand, I still don't see how it would make sense to have some mandatory time off to address this. The gist of my answer is it's unnecessary for most people. And yet it fails to address many other situations (like the ones I mentioned in my comments) or to effectively prevent a malicious employer from making it impossible to vote (say by sending you to the other end of the country). Proxy voting does address all this.

Comment: The issue is that you need to register for a proxy vote well in advance so it doesn't help unless your boss gives you plenty of warning. What I am arguing is that the boss should be required to give this notice by law.

Comment: @Lembik Maybe. It still sounds like a partial solution to a far-fetched problem to me. But really I did not mean to argue one way or the other and certainly not to discuss what should be done about employers with a malicious intent. I am just trying to explain the logic of the law as I understand it.

Comment: Note that in many other European countries, voting takes place on Sunday and employers have to inform employees of their work hours in advance in any case (i.e. not as a measure to prevent voting manipulation but as a basic right). Either of these seem like a much simpler solution to this problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

So far as I know, there is no obligation on a UK employer to allow an employee time off to vote.

There is a legal obligation on employers to allow employees time off to perform certain "public duties", notably jury service. See this gov.uk link for more: https://www.gov.uk/time-off-work-public-duties

However voting is not a public duty. Furthermore the legal obligation above does not apply to all employers in all circumstances.

I speak of the law as it currently is. Whether it should be different is a separate question.